# Edge on ALT-TAB to show its windows not tabs

Tags: windows, browser, microsoft-edge

On Windows -- `ALT-TAB` allows switching between the currently-open windows, also allows closing them if you wanted to.

`Edge` browser, however, shows all its recent tabs i used as separate windows on this feature.
so, if i have say 10 Edge tabs open on one Edge window and i used 4 of them this AM, i see all that 4 (non-sleeping tabs?) as separate windows when i do `ALT-TAB`, and not just as 1 window like the other browsers do.
how to set Edge so that it shows by its windows, not each of its tabs on `ALT-TAB`?

can't see anything on its `Settings`

letting me put tabs to sleep in 5mins instead of the default 1hr -- "Put inactive tabs to sleep after the specified amount of time" but that's not enough

i use this `ALT-TAB` v.often and
all those tabs there is really cluttering up the view

TIA

searched on internet, on Stackoverflow and on Edge's own menus

Answer (score 47, accepted):

(**EDIT:** These changes have to be made to your Windows OS, not in the settings of your Edge browser!)

[image]

If you don't want ALT+TAB to show the browser tabs (but show them as one process), you can go to **(System) Settings > System > Multitasking > Alt + Tab**, and select **Open windows only**.

[image]

Comment: The procedure indicated by @Kendrick Li answer is to be done in Windows (and not in Edge)

Comment: It seems the name of the settings has changed to "Show tabs from apps when snapping or pressing Alt+Tab". You can set this setting to "Don't show tabs" for the same effect.

Comment: On Windows 11, look for the option *Show tabs from apps when snapping or pressing Alt+Tab* and select *Don't show tabs*.

Comment: Thankyou, the multiple tabs were driving me nuts!

Comment: Any idea how to do this on Windows 11?

Comment: in Win 11 choose Don't show tabs